# Convert RGB32 image to ofPixels in Open Frameworks

Tags: c++, video-streaming, openframeworks

I am trying to display a video from a video decoder library.
The video is delivered as a byte array with RGB32 pixel format.
Meaning every pixel is represented by 32 bits.

RRBBGGFF - 8bit R, 8bit G, 8bit B, 8bit 0xFF.

Similar to QT Qimage Format_RGB32.

I thnik I need to convert the pixel array to ofPixels, Then load the pixels to ofTexture.
Then I can draw the texture.

I don't know how to convert/set the ofPixels from this pixel format.

Any tips/ideas are so so welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `ofThreadChannel` as described in [this example](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/tree/master/examples/threads/threadChannelExample) in order to avoid writing and reading from your `ofTexture` / `ofPixels`.

Then you can load a `uint8_t*` by doing :

by using an `ofTexture`'s method [`loadFromPixels()`](https://openframeworks.cc/documentation/gl/ofTexture/#show_loadData) :

```cpp
// assuming data is populating the externalBuffer
void* externalBuffer;
tex.loadFromPixels((uint8*)externalData, width, height, GL_RGBA);
```

Hope this helps,

Best,

P